# how to load jar:file: uri in swt browser?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, swt

I cannot load a `jar:file` uri in a swt browser. The same uri loads fine in my firefox, and it does load with older versions of the same software. The only change I could spot was that the old working version depends - seemingly with no reason - on `org.eclipse.core.resources`.
However after recreating the dependency, the page still does not load.

I have this in the browser window:

```
Unable to load page

Problem occurred while loading the URL file:///usr/share/zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.help_2.4.0.201401091630.jar!/hints/viewpoint_total.html

Error opening file: No such file or directory
```

I have found no sign of any exception, and no trace in the log.

The actual uri in the above case was:

```
jar:file:/usr/share/zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.help_2.4.0.201401091630.jar!/hints/viewpoint_total.html
```

I am using this code:

```
    win.shell.pack();
    win.shell.open();
    Browser fBrowser = new Browser(win.getComposite(), SWT.NONE);
    GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    fBrowser.setLayoutData(gd);
    fBrowser.pack();

    String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String url = "jar:file:/usr/share/zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.help_2.4.0.201401091630.jar!/hints/viewpoint_total.html"
    System.out.printf("cwd=%s\nurl=%s\n", cwd, url);
    fBrowser.setUrl(url);
    fBrowser.setFocus();
```

As a bonus question: is there a way to detect such failures of the browser, so when a solution is found, I could write a unit test for it?

Comment: Actually the problem was not due to different version, but to different build.
It seems the swt browser was never able to open such an url (while mozilla is).
The url in question came from one of my bundles. In eclipse build the bundle in question was packaged as a directory, while in the maven build it was packaged as jar, because tycho disregards the root.folder property.
However I could add Eclipse-BundleShape: dir to the MANIFEST.MF, which is acted upon by tycho.
Thanks for the answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the resource using `JarUrlConnection`:

```
  try {
    InputStream in;
    String url = "jar:file:/usr/share/zenta/plugins/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.help_2.4.0.201401091630.jar!/hints/viewpoint_total.html"
    JarURLConnection con = (JarURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    in = con.getInputStream();
    // read the stream
  } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    System.err.println("Malformed URL: "+url);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("IO error");
  } finally {
    in.close();
  }
```